# Operators/Assignments/Thingies About Classes (Java)

Tags: java

Not exactly sure how to phrase this, sorry for ambiguous title. 
Anyways, here's basically my cuestión.

Basically, I know how I can pass values into the class using the contructor and functions and such, like,

```
class bob {
    int value;
    public bob(int x) {
        value = x;
    }
}

bob test = bob(5);
```

But how do you handle things like operators and such? Like, if a person added the classes together:

```
bob test1 = bob(5), test2 = bob(3), test3 = test1 + test2;
```

How could I make it actually do something is a person tried to add the two instantiated objects together?

Or if I said something like,

```
bob test = 5;
```

How could I do something with a value you initialize it to have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do either in Java. Java's operators only work for primitive types (and String as a special exception), and regular objects can only be initialized with compatible objects or `null`.

Instead, you should define appropriate methods and constructors:

```
public bob add(bob other) { ... }
```

then use

```
bob test1 = new bob(5);
bob test2 = new bob(3);
bob test3 = test1.add(test2);
```

Since you can't do `bob test = 5;`, just do `bob test = new bob(5);`.

Comment: Ah. I was thinking you could, because of how the String class functions.

Answer (score 0):

Java isn't C++.  You can't invoke a constructor without the `new` keyword (unless you use reflection, but that's another topic entirely).  You also can't override operators like `+` to work with custom object types either.

Instead, if it's semantically appropriate add one instance of your object type to another, you do it by defining an `add()` method, like:

```
class Bob {
    int value;
    public Bob(int x) {
        value = x;
    }

    public Bob add(Bob other) {
        return new Bob(this.value + (other == null ? 0 : other.value));
    }
}
```

And then:

```
Bob test1 = new Bob(5);
Bob test2 = new Bob(3);
Bob test3 = test1.add(test2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class declaration is correct. (In an entirely unrelated subject, by convention, Java classes should start with capital letters. I.e., your class should be named Bob. But that's not germane to the question...)

The proper syntax for creating an object and passing parameters into the constructor is:

```
Bob test = new Bob(5);
```

As for addition, you can't work with the operators directly. There are languages that allow you to specify what operators do to objects, but Java isn't one of them. (You can Google up on operator overloading for more info on this.)

If you want addition type stuff, you actually have to define a function for it. In your case, there's two things you can do:

You can define an instance function:

```
class Bob {
// The other stuff you listed, like the constructor and the private field
    public Bob add(Bob other) {
        return new Bob(value + (other == null ? 0 : other.value));
    }
}
```

Or, you can define a static function:

```
class Bob {
// The other stuff you listed, like the constructor and the private field
    public static Bob add(Bob one, Bob other) {
        return new Bob((one == null ? 0 : one.value) + (other == null ? 0 : other.value));
    }
}
```

The first one, you call with

```
test3 = test1.add(test2);
```

The second one, you call with

```
test3 = Bob.add(test1, test2);
```